# Iterating through DataFrame rows to create new column while referencing other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe I am working with that contains fudamental data for equities. Below are images of the head and tail of the dataframe (data). It has data for each security and each year from 2005-2015. Note the 'calendardate' column.

My goal is to go to each row, take the 'revenueusd' datapoint and divide it by the 'revenueusd' datapoint for the year before to get the 1 year revenue growth change for each security. The second datapoint is located using the ticker and calendardate.

I have been trying to use the apply function with a lambda but it is not working. Below is the code I have been trying:

```
def conversion(tick, dates,dataframe):
    date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    date2 = datetime.date(date1.year-1,date1.month,date1.day).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    growth = dataframe[(dataframe['ticker']==tick)&(dataframe['calendardate']==dates)]['revenueusd']/dataframe[(dataframe['ticker']==tick)&(dataframe['calendardate']==date2)]['revenueusd']-1
    return growth

data['1yrRevenueGrowth']=data.apply(lambda x: conversion(x['ticker'],x['calendardate'],data),axis=1)
```

I have been stuck on this for days and searching the forums relentlessly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[data.head(5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAdEa.png)

[data.tail(5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYDEq.png)

```
,ticker,ticker.1,calendardate,revenueusd,gp,rnd  
0,A,A,2015-12-31,4038000000,2041000000,330000000  
1,AA,AA,2015-12-31,22534000000,4465000000,238000000  
2,AAL,AAL,2015-12-31,40990000000,23911000000,0  
3,AAP,AAP,2015-12-31,9737018000,4422772000,0  
4,AAPL,AAPL,2015-12-31,234988000000,94308000000,8576000000  
5,ABBV,ABBV,2015-12-31,22859000000,18359000000,4435000000  
509,A,A,2014-12-31,6981000000,3593000000,719000000  
510,AA,AA,2014-12-31,23906000000,4769000000,218000000  
511,AAPL,AAPL,2014-12-31,199800000000,78432000000,6606000000  
512,ABBV,ABBV,2014-12-31,19960000000,15534000000,3649000000
```

Comment: Instead of linking to an image, please include a sample of your data in the text of your question.

Comment: What is the best way to do this? I have tried including it in the text and it looks very sloppy. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Just copy and paste a section of your DataFrame and use the formatting tools in the StackOverflow editor to format it as if it were code.  It's also a good idea to include the code that generates the data, or a snippet of the data in a CSV-like format that's easy for other people to cut and paste and load themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have added a sample of the data in the text in CSV format. Let me know if that is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice function called [Series.pct_change](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) for your purpose. You could do it for example like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=0)
data.groupby("ticker").apply(lambda x : x.set_index("calendardate").sort_index()["revenueusd"].pct_change())
```

For each ticker value, a series is constructed that is sorted by the calendar date and then the function `pct_change`is applied (by default this function computes the ratio between two consecutive entries).

```
ticker  calendardate
A       2014-12-31           NaN
        2015-12-31     -0.421573
AA      2014-12-31           NaN
        2015-12-31     -0.057391
AAL     2015-12-31           NaN
AAP     2015-12-31           NaN
AAPL    2014-12-31           NaN
        2015-12-31      0.176116
ABBV    2014-12-31           NaN
        2015-12-31      0.145240
Name: revenueusd, dtype: float64
```

One more thing, your dates are nicely formatted so you can easily convert the column to type datetime like this:

```
data["calendardate"] = pd.to_datetime(data["calendardate"], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this:

```
 ticker ticker.1 calendardate   revenueusd          gp      rnd  
0      A        A   2015-12-31   4038000000  2041000000  330000000
1     AA       AA   2015-12-31  22534000000  4465000000  238000000
2      A        A   2014-12-31    403800000   204100000  330000000
3     AA       AA   2014-12-31   2253400000   446500000  238000000
4      A        A   2013-12-31    403800000    20410000  330000000
5     AA       AA   2013-12-31    225340000    44650000  238000000
6      A        A   2012-12-31       403800     2041000  330000000
7     AA       AA   2012-12-31     22534000     4465000  238000000


df["pct"] =  df.groupby("ticker")['revenueusd'].pct_change()



 ticker ticker.1 calendardate   revenueusd          gp      rnd      pct
0      A        A   2015-12-31   4038000000  2041000000  330000000    NaN
1     AA       AA   2015-12-31  22534000000  4465000000  238000000    NaN
2      A        A   2014-12-31    403800000   204100000  330000000 -0.900
3     AA       AA   2014-12-31   2253400000   446500000  238000000 -0.900
4      A        A   2013-12-31    403800000    20410000  330000000  0.000
5     AA       AA   2013-12-31    225340000    44650000  238000000 -0.900
6      A        A   2012-12-31       403800     2041000  330000000 -0.999
7     AA       AA   2012-12-31     22534000     4465000  238000000 -0.900
```

You may need to **sort DataFrame prior to applying groupby**.

Comment: Perhaps `.apply(lambda x : x.pct_change())` the same as `.pct_change()` ?